# BATCH Programing - Get number out of a string

Tags: batch-file, window, batch-processing

I have a .txt file on my machine. In that file there is a line

'All things complete. (\d+) script command executed'

where (\d+) is any number.

Through batch script I have to find if above string appears in the file and get the number that appear between the string.

Is it possible . Can anyone help me here.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=4" %%f in (
    'findstr /r /c:"All things complete. [0-9]*" file.txt'
) do echo %%f
```

Search the indicated line with findstr, and use `for` command, splitting on spaces an getting the fourth token.